# Как пояснить perforce-jam системе сборки какой компилятор (gcc) должен он использовать

Tags: c++, gcc

Я пытаюсь создать "hello world - проект" использующий

- Jam (perforce) система сборки
- C++
- Linux
- arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc *компилятор*

**helloworld-perforce-jam.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int args, char* argv[])
{

    printf("\n\n\nHello World from HELLOWORLD-PERFORCE-JAM!!!\n\n\n\n");
    return 0; 
}
```

**Jamfile**

```
Echo $(CC) ;
Main helloworld-perforce-jam : helloworld-perforce-jam.cpp ;
```

Никаких проблем если я использую **arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc** напрямую в обход Jam (система сборки) как показана ниже:

```
ygyerts@ygyerts:$ /home/user/full_path/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc helloworld-perforce-jam.cpp
```

Успешно создается бинарь для Linux **ARM**.

Никаких проблем если я испозую gcc по умолчанию (что определен самой системой сборки Jam), пример:

```
ygyerts@ygyerts:$ jam
cc 
...found 66 target(s)...
...updating 1 target(s)...
Link helloworld-perforce-jam 
Chmod1 helloworld-perforce-jam 
...updated 1 target(s)...
```

Создается бинарь, только не тот что нужен, он предназначен для !!!**x86 architecture**!!!.
Идея в том чтобы использовать предопределенный gcc компилятор (/home/user/full_path/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc). Это блокер, я не знаю как объяснить системе сборки Jam какой компилятор использовать...

Я игрался с параметрами запуска сборки как указано ниже:

```
ygyerts@ygyerts:$ jam -s CC=/home/user/full_path/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc
/home/user/full_path/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc
...found 66 target(s)...
...updating 2 target(s)...
C++ helloworld-perforce-jam.o 
Link helloworld-perforce-jam 
helloworld-perforce-jam.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

/home/ygyerts/TOOLING/TeamCity/TeamCity-9.1.7/buildAgent/work/e58af29ade3fd40c/fsl-community-bsp/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -o helloworld-perforce-jam  helloworld-perforce-jam.o   

...failed Link helloworld-perforce-jam ...
...failed updating 1 target(s)...
...updated 1 target(s)...
```

Помогите пожалуйста мне понять что я должен установить в билд окружение-переменных для того что бы успешно сбилдить мой пример helloworld для arm-linux архитектуры, не для x86_64-linux...